# windows 8.1 extremely long login

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, performance, login, safe-mode

Hello I have just bought new computer. Asus g550jk.
It came without Os, so i have installed win8.1 . It worked fine at the start but after few drivers and windows updates it developed very long login phase. Computer starts up from turned off to login in about 8 seconds but it takes 40 seconds after login for desktop to appear.

I have tried:
clean start. Same thing.

What is there to do?

Edit: abit faster in safe mode: like 10 seconds..

Comment: Sounds like a conflicting driver.  Start removing what you installed until it behaves itself then DON"T install the misbehaving driver again.

Comment: @Ramhound I agree, it does sound like that. could it be windows updates?

Comment: capture a boot trace: http://pastebin.com/CYGqRZXE

Comment: What you linked to isn't helpful, go with my suggestion, guaranteed to work

Comment: as Ramhound said it will be better to remove the drivers that was installed during latest update. In case if you need any drivers for sure try installing it from device manager --  Update Driver Software

Comment: I would use [Process Monitor]( http://technet.microsoft.com/cs-cz/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to analyze the startup, just enable boot logging in options. Then we can move on.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try the [Windows Restore point](http://windows.microsoft.com/hu-hu/windows7/create-a-restore-point)

If you're lucky, the windows create restore points before installed for you drivers or updates.
Try the oldest, if you have it.